# Custom LinearLayout with EditText inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

You will understand my problem if you do it step by step as mentioned below (sorry, But I can't make you understand in other way). This might be confusing. But, I am sure if you read it once, you will understand.

1. Create a new android project, then create two Fragments. You will now 
   have

   a. MainActivity.java.

   b. FirstFragment(FirstFragment.java) with it's xml 
         file(first_fragment.xml).

   c. SecondFragment(SecondFragment.java) with it's xml 
         file(second_fragment.xml).

Now create a custom linearLayout class (FormRow.java) as below:

```
public class FormRowNew extends LinearLayout {
    public FormRowNew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.form_row, this);
    }
}
```

xml file (form_row) in this is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="eeeee"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this Custom linear class TWICE inside FirstFragment like below:

```
<gallery.com.yyyyyyyyy.FormRow
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txvFirst"
    >
</gallery.com.yyyyyyyyy.FormRow>

<gallery.com.yyyyyyyyy.FormRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first"
    >
</gallery.com.yyyyyyyyy.FormRow>
```

REMEMBER: I have used it twice. You also use it AT LEAST TWICE.

Now, load FirstFragment in MainActivity.java at some id (rlRootLayout) like below.

```
FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)                                                                       
.replace(R.id.rlRootLayout, firstFragment).commit();
```

Similarly, load Second Fragment at same ID (rlRootLayout) from FirstFragment like below.

```
secondFragment blankFragment = new secondFragment();
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.addToBackS tack(null).replace(R.id.rlRootLayout, blankFragment)
.commit();
```

Here i am adding SecondFragment to MainActivity from FirstFragment 
at ID(rlRootLayout).

Problem :- Run the app and go to page as mentioned :

```
 MainActivity -> 
 FirstFragment -> 
 Change something in BOTTOM FormRow(like add some text in EditText) ->
 SecondFragment ->
 FirstFragment.
```

Now, See the custom classes (FormRow) inside FirstFragment. 
Whatever We had added in bottom FormRow class, automatically added in Top FormRow. I couldn't find the reason why is this happening. Even if I am doing nothing with top FormRow, it changes according to bottom when I come back from SecondFragment. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Save the text in editText while adding second fragment. Then set those saved text while going back to first from second this

```java
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    //set edit text
}
```

is called.

Comment: this one helps me  @Arjun

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is because of the id of the `EditText`. When the first fragment is inflating the layout while going back from the second fragment, the it assigns the values to edit text by using it id. So in this case both `EditText`'s has the same id so it assigns the same value for the both Edittexts's